# The accuracy of my validation set is always the same

Tags: validation, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN model which is used for a multi-label classification task. My training data set has 5000 data points, every data point is a 100000 long 1-D array. So the shape of my training set is (5000,100000).

[The CNN model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xggmo.png). The picture shows the structure of my CNN model. The problem I have encountered right now is that the accuracy of my validation set is always the exactly same (always 0.88) no matter how I modify the model.

```
Epoch 1/10
79/79 [==============================] - 36s 445ms/step - loss: 0.3915 - binary_accuracy: 0.8705 - val_loss: 0.3892 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8800
Epoch 2/10
79/79 [==============================] - 34s 426ms/step - loss: 0.3711 - binary_accuracy: 0.8800 - val_loss: 0.3714 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8800
Epoch 3/10
79/79 [==============================] - 34s 425ms/step - loss: 0.3702 - binary_accuracy: 0.8800 - val_loss: 0.3872 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8800
```

I have tried to change the number of filter and kernel size, the number of layers, and the convelutional function(I used CONV2D before). And I've standardized my data set. I want to know what might be contributing to this problem, or where I can modify in my model. Thank you in advance for your help!

Any possible aspect would be very helpful to me. I want to understand why this is happening and where I can make adjustments.

Comment: As written, your model is basically incapable of recognizing features more than 45 timesteps long. Most likely all of your other "tweaked" designs were also not good enough to outperform a constant function. (Do you happen to have one class that makes up 88% of the examples?). You need to understand the problem and design a model that actually suits it. You haven't given any specific information here so we can't even begin to help with that.

Comment: Oops, 5, not 45.

Comment: @hobbs Thank you for your response. As someone new to deep learning, I'm trying to better understand what you mean by "incapable of recognizing features more than 5 timesteps long." Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @Jamesharden Imagine you have a song and you're trying to determine whether or not it's a lost work of Led Zeppelin. Your idea is to get 16 people and play each one 100,000 different snippets of the song, and ask them to rate each snippet for likelihood of being Zeppelin. Out of all of the billions of the people in the world, you choose the 16 who score most accurately on a test of known Zeppelin and non-Zeppelin songs. But one problem — each snippet they have to listen to and rate is 1 millisecond long, and the scorers no memory of previous ones they've heard.

Comment: @Jamesharden That's what `Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=5)` is. It's 16 people who get to listen to 1 millisecond snippets of a song, in random order, with amnesia, and who are supposed to tell you whether or not they hear Led Zeppelin after each one.

Comment: @hobbs Thank you for your explaination. Based on what you've mentioned, does this imply that my feature space might be too large for my current kernel size, thereby hindering accurate judgments? Should I consider increasing my kernel size to better capture the features?